# Writing a PLSQL select in array

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle

I'm using a DB 'A' to output a list of numbers :

```
123455
123456
123457
```

And I'm looking to build a dynamic statement to look into a DB 'B' with those results as a filter

a. Build an array with the values from DB 'A'

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE number in &array;
```

How can I achieve this ?

The DB 'B' is an **Oracle** DB.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have database `A` which is a (remote) non-Oracle database and database `B` which is a (local) Oracle database and you want to generate a list of numbers on on the remote database `A` and use it (or copy/paste it) on database `B`? Are you running your `SELECT * FROM my_table` on database `A` or `B`? Can you set up a database link? Can you copy/paste or transfer files between `A` and `B`?

Comment: I want to run the select ... where number in &array in DB B (Oracle).

DB A is only used to provide the list to the variable "array"
I cannot join DB A & B with a DB link.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Looks like your  "background" is not Oracle, because there are no "DB"s there. I mean, there *are*, but not in a context you're using them. If "DB" stands for a "Database", to me it looks as if you're actually talking about **tables** here.

Also, I don't understand what

> The DB 'B' is in PLSQL means.

If "database" is a table, how is it in PL/SQL?

---

Anyway, to get you started: I'm fetching some data from Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables. For collections, I'm using Oracle's built-in types.

These are employees in departments 10 and 20:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename
  2  from emp
  3  where deptno in (10, 20)
  4  order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO ENAME
---------- ----------
        10 CLARK
        10 KING
        10 MILLER
        20 ADAMS
        20 FORD
        20 JONES
        20 SCOTT
        20 SMITH

8 rows selected.
```

PL/SQL procedure which does *something* with them (the way I understood the question):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_a sys.odcinumberlist;
  3    l_b sys.odcivarchar2list;
  4  begin
  5    select deptno
  6      bulk collect into l_a
  7      from dept
  8      where deptno in (10, 20);
  9
 10    select ename
 11      bulk collect into l_b
 12      from emp
 13      where deptno in (select * from table(l_a))
 14      order by ename;
 15
 16    for i in l_b.first .. l_b.last loop
 17      dbms_output.put_line(l_b(i));
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /
ADAMS
CLARK
FORD
JONES
KING
MILLER
SCOTT
SMITH

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- Lines #1 - 3 - declaration section
- lines #5 - 8 - inserting values (departments) into `l_a` collection
- Lines #10 - 14 - inserting values (employees) into `l_b` collection, based on values stored in `l_a`
- Lines #16 - 18 - displaying contents of `l_b`

See if it helps.

---

**[EDIT]** After seeing your comment: as far as I can tell, you can't do what you wanted, not as simple as you'd want it to. This is how it *works* - you enter a comma-separated values as a parameter (that's your "array"), split it into rows and use the result as a subquery:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM dept
  3   WHERE deptno IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( '&&par_depts',
  4                                              '[^,]+',
  5                                              1,
  6                                              LEVEL)
  7                          FROM DUAL
  8                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT ( '&&par_depts', ',') + 1);
Enter value for par_depts: 10,20

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS

SQL>
```

This is a SQL*Plus example; you'll probably have to substitute `'&&par_depts'` with `:par_depts` (depending on a tool you use).

Comment: @Jonathan PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language; it is not a database (or a type of database).

Comment: Yes sorry, abuse of language. An Oracle DB.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: My question was not correctly formulated. I'm not looking for a PL/SQL procedure. I'm just looking to do a select with an array as a variable like this "SELECT * from yyyy where variable in &array" where i define the variable 'array' with a list of numbers.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more info; have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MEMBER` operator.

First create a collection type in SQL:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF INT;
```

Then just use it in an SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  value MEMBER OF int_list(123455, 123456, 123457);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( id, value ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 123453 + LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 123455 |
> | 3 | 123456 |
> | 4 | 123457 |

---

If you want it in PL/SQL then:

```sql
DECLARE
  items int_list := int_list(123455, 123456, 123457);
BEGIN
  FOR row IN (
               SELECT *
               FROM   my_table
               WHERE  value MEMBER OF items
             )
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( row.id || ', ' || row.value );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the same data, outputs:

> ```
> 2, 123455
> 3, 123456
> 4, 123457
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=91fa4fd3aa31e60b1478f0b826953b23)*

---

However, if you just want to connect two databases then setup a database link.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
Is their a way to do this without creating a table ?

Comment: @Jonathan You need to have the table `my_table` to be able to `SELECT` from. Creating it in the answer is just replicating the setup that you use in the question; so presumably you already have that table and do not need to recreate it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.
Is their a way to do this without creating a table ?


I just want to do check more efficiently.
Sometimes I need to check results with a basic


select xx, yy, zz 
from my_table mt
inner join my_second_table mst on mt.xx=mst.xx
where mt.bbb in (
MY LIST
);


I just want to check if I can do it faster by using a variable / an array "my_list"

So the select query is always the same, and I only need to change the variable / the array.

Regards,

Comment: You're quick. Did not have time to edit my comment, posted too quickly

Comment: My question was not correctly formulated. I'm not looking for a PL/SQL procedure. I'm just looking to do a select with an array as a variable like this "SELECT * from yyyy where variable in &array" where i define the variable 'array' with a list of numbers. Don't know if you can help my with that.

Comment: @Jonathan `&variable` is a substitution variable (and is supported by SQL/plus and SQL Developer) and will just replace the variable with the value as if you had done a find-replace in a text editor. Just use `SELECT * FROM yyyy WHERE variable IN (&array)` and then set the substitution variable to `123455, 123456, 123457` (with the numbers comma-delimited).